# How to install Istio ingress,egress and other components as DeamonSet in Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, istio, rancher, rancher-rke

```
Environment :
- Single Cluster.
- Cluster Managed by Rancher.
```

We have a HA (High Availability) requirement where we want to deploy multiple replicas of Ingress, Egress as DaemonSet to handle heavy load.

I went through the istio documentation and site, to understand deployment models, but it doesnt achieve the usecase.

Comment: I tried with istio and made it working. But i  am not sure whether it is  possible to do it in HA with replicaset

Answer (score 1):

I did the istio operator way of installing and used the below Manifest file :

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: istio-operator-ha-config
spec:
  components:
    ingressGateways:
       - name: istio-ingressgateway
         enabled: true
         k8s:
           overlays:
            - apiVersion: apps/v1
              kind: Deployment
              name: istio-ingressgateway
              patches:
              - path: kind
                value: DaemonSet
    egressGateways:
       - name: istio-egressgateway
         enabled: true
         k8s:
           overlays:
            - apiVersion: apps/v1
              kind: Deployment
              name: istio-egressgateway
              patches:
              - path: kind
                value: DaemonSet
```

See : https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/install/operator/